# Insert text from bluetooth keyboard on tvOS

Tags: objective-c, tvos

Does `tvOS` support direct typing when focusing on an `UITextField` using a bluetooth keyboard? My problem is that when connecting a bluetooth keyboard and focusing on my `UITextField` and starting to type, the `UITextField` ignores my input. However, if I press once the return/enter button it triggers the on-screen keyboard. There my keyboard key presses are recognized and I can insert text.
Is this by design or do I need to listen to the key presses and update the text field content by hand?

Comment: I think it's currently impossible. [See my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48949851/can-the-apple-tv-hide-the-on-screen-keyboard). Maybe you can try to build on my attempts at hiding the default `inputView` and report back if you have any luck, or even if you get a bit further and hit new exceptions.